# how to loop call token transfer function in a single transaction

Tags: transactions, contract-invocation

I find a transaction [here](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xdd5f5c62af3b34d0ac408867cae469f721aa9cd49cd2458d5140617d6a9db3f9) which contains multiple inner transfers. It seems that it saves a lot gas. May I do this with web3j?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the input data for that transaction, it's calling the function `sendTokensSingleValue(address[] dests, uint256 value)`. Although the code isn't verified on Etherscan, the function name and the arguments imply the function is iterating over the `dests` array and sendinng `value` to each. You could do it with web3j, but you'd have to create a contract with that function.

Comment: If my token contract already deployed, do I need to deploy a new contract again, and again spend the deployment gas?

Comment: Yes, you will have to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Add an example for this kind of requirement: [Airdropper.sol](https://github.com/omisego/airdrop/blob/master/contracts/Airdropper.sol)
This is basically looping to call the token `transfer` method, and pay close attention to the keyword `onlyOwner`.
There is another [tutorial](https://github.com/indorseio/airdrop/blob/master/indorser.sol) which has a serious security issue as it doesn't check the sender ownership before transfer.